# Comparing each char in two strings and incrementing: Python

Tags: python, string, compare

```
for x in predRslt:
    for y in actRslt:
        if x == y and x =='1':
            trueP += 1
        elif x == y and x =='0':
            trueN += 1
        elif x != y and x == '1':
            falseN += 1      
        elif x != y and x == '0':
            falseP += 1

    charNum += 1
totalActN = trueN + falseP
totalActP = falseN + trueP
totalPredN = trueN + falseN
totalPredP = trueP + falseP

print falseP
```

cmp_rslt('0110101001','1100100101')

actual output: 25

expected output: 2

Im trying to go through each string sequentailly from the beginning and compare the results. Then increment the corresponding TrueN, TrueP, FalseN, or FalseP.

for some reason, I keep getting an output of 25 when I should be getting way less than that because there's only 10 comparisons I should be making

Answer (score 0):

you should iterate using the index of the first string like this:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(predRslt);
    y = actRslt[idx]

    if x == y and x =='1':         
        trueP += 1
    elif x == y and x =='0':
        trueN += 1
    elif x != y and x == '1':
        falseN += 1      
    elif x != y and x == '0':
        falseP += 1
```

Comment: perfect! that worked. Can you explain why mine did not work? and what exactly the code was calculating in my version?

Comment: Sure, your version was iterating twice, once over the "prediction results", and for each prediction result, you were iterating over the "actual results", which caused the large number of comparisons. If you iterate only through one of the lists (e.g. "prediction results"), then making sure you share the same "index" when accessing the "actual results" you should be good to go.  Hope this helps!